# Get user list of owned apps facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

How can I get the list of apps ids owned by me via the Facebook graph API?

I tried using the graph api explorer: [graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) with this url:

> me?fields=accounts which gives me the user accounts.

My question is how to get the user owned apps ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no way.**

Earlier it was possible with this endpoint: `me/applications/developer`

The result:

> User/applications endpoint is deprecated for versions v2.6 and higher

Comment: Thanks, do you think its possible to get this data for API previous than 2.6? When trying this I get no data even though there should be

Comment: it may be possible, but i would not count on it and sooner or later it will be gone anyway, so why even bother? if you don´t get any data, it´s probably removed even for older APIs.

Comment: v2.5 is available until 12. April 2018, so it really does not make any sense to  build an app with stuff that will definitely be gone in april this year...

Answer (score 0):

On version v2.11, I believe you are looking for: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/applications?access_token=USERACCESSTOKEN&type=developer`

Comment: Apologies, was using a FB Ads Manager token when I made the request and it worked on v2.11. Potentially, you could use the Business Manager API to retrieve App IDs if you have them tied to BM, and just batch the calls?

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/businesses?access_token=USERACCESSTOKEN`

then

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/BUSINESSID/owned_apps?access_token=USERACCESSTOKEN`